Aluminum tube deflection
We're designing a new start bar for the Harris Hill Ski Jump in Brattleboro, VT. It's the bar the jumper slides out to sit on as he/she awaits the okay to go.
Will the tube specs below be sufficient to support the skier?
The bar length is 8ft and is supported at each end.
The maximum weight of a jumper might reach 175lb. Historically, 150lb would likely be the max.
Can anyone comment on the deflection of this aluminum tube?
6061 Aluminum Round Tube, 3-1/2 OD x .125 wall x 3.250 ID
Many thanks for any insights.

Having worked with 6061T6 aluminum tube in the past, smaller diameter than your test case, I feel that you'll have no problems. Eighth-inch wall of that diameter is huge, in terms of strength. Having both ends supported only makes things better. Just a layman's view, no calculations to back it up. I'm looking forward to seeing the true engineering analysis.

What are the specs of the existing bar? A simple comparison should show if it will perform better...

If all you care about is deflection, model as point load for beam bending?
